# XRDP on Ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, xrdp

I installed a clean Ubuntu18.04 with minimal installation and installed the xrdp package.

After the XRDP user/password there is a password prompt in ubuntu for my user popping up. When I enter it the connection just dies and the connection windows dissapears.

Does anyone got xrdp running on the 18.04 release yet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it should work...I know that you did a clean install, but can you try doing `sudo apt-get purge --autoremove xrdp`, reboot, then reinstall it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works fine with my desktop!

[image: picture - success login xrdp]

The good news is it works good with Nvidia drivers so far.

However there is still some issue to be fixed:

1. **If you are not logout in local, the remote login would fail.**
2. It would ask you to input password after login once again.

   [image: picture - password again]
3. After login, it would ask for a authentication.

   [image: picture - authentication never pass]

   And this authenticate would never pass unless you click cancel. (Just cancel it, then you can get in the Desktop.)

to avoid the authenticate popup,you might execute the command below
(provide by [this post](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11868)):

```
sudo bash -c "cat >/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/45-allow.colord.pkla" <<EOF
[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
EOF
```

If the problem is not solved, I'll suggest you to:

1. Install drivers by:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
   ```
2. Log out any local logged-in account.

Comment: So what exactly is this command supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 5):

**To answer the OPs question:**

Ubuntu didn't work until I added `gnome-session` to `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh`. I commented out the `test` and `exec` lines at the bottom of the file and added `gnome-session` (not sure if that was the correct way to do it or not... but it worked).

It prompts me for access to create a color correction device. I authenticated and had to reboot for the prompts to go away.

**If you're going to try other flavors, here is what I found:**

I just did a fresh install of 18.04 UbuntuBudgie, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, and Ubuntu. Only Kubuntu worked with XRDP out of the box on bare metal with hardline networking.

Kubuntu gives you a desktop but nags you about a network connections policy. I removed the network widget from the system tray and it worked without hassle after that. This was the smoothest experience of the ones I tried out.

Xubuntu didn't work out of the box (This fixed it - [How to configure XRDP to start  cinnamon as default desktop session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135483/how-to-configure-xrdp-to-start-cinnamon-as-default-desktop-session) - See the section that has `startxfce4` in there which amounts to adding `startxfce4` to `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh`).

UbuntuBudgie didn't work until I added `budgie-desktop` to `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh`. Again not sure if that was the "correct" way to do it but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I run my XRDP installation on a KVM virtual machine, and thus it won't work without installing the `xorgxrdp` -package.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing similar in Kubuntu 18.04. 
If you are logged in locally and you try to XRDP into the same machine, the session will disconnect (no errors, just disconnect).
I have found the opposite is true also - if you disconnect an XRDP session without logging out, then try logging in locally you get disconnected.
Maybe there is a setting somewhere to allow multiple sessions?

Comment: I have found a second user can login on XRDP while another is logged in locally. I think this confirms the idea that there is a limit on the number of allowed logins. I might use a second user ID for remote access until I can figure out how to adust it.

Answer (score 0):

Read / Do this:
http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11868 <--Before execute the downloaded script (Std-Xrdp-Install-0.2.sh) Do this:
Edit the downloaded script and:

1. Remove the part where is checking you Ubuntu version (Only if are you sure that you have Ubuntu Desktop 18.04), save and execute the script, then...
2. Restart all you Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 and do not login, in Windows side connect using remote desktop.

*Tip:* If can not connect to Ubuntu 18.04, login in Ubuntu 18.04 and type this in a terminal: `sudo systemctl enable xrdp`, then restart your Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 again and do not login in, go to Windows side and try the connection again using remote desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have created and tested a script to auto install and configure xRDP on Ubuntu 18.04 which installs:

- xrdp
- mate-session
- gnome-session
- xfce4-session

You can then easily change the desktop in `~/.xsession`

```
mate-session # Works
#gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check & gnome-panel # Works
#xfce4-session # Works
```

**GIST:** https://gist.github.com/djravine/88f2b9957a0bef6a6dd4c55aca951a09

**USAGE:** `curl -sL https://gist.github.com/djravine/88f2b9957a0bef6a6dd4c55aca951a09/raw | bash -s --`