# XRDP starts wrong Desktop (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, xrdp

I have updated my Ubuntu Mate 16.04 to 18.04 and installed the new Gnome standard Desktop. When I want to access the PC via XRDP, I can only connect to the Mate Desktop, but not to the Gnome Desktop.

I changed the ~/.xsessionrc file to the following, but it still starts the Mate Desktop when I connect:

```
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=${D}
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
```

Can anyone help me to get the Gnome Desktop started?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031519/xrdp-on-ubuntu-18-04lts, may help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert with XRDP but also I would check your ~/.xsession file to make sure it contains "gnome-session" (without quotes).