# how to switch desktop environment from terminal (remote access)?

Tags: server, ubuntu-gnome

I'm logging to Ubuntu server via RDP the default environment on that server is Xfce how can I switch this environment to gnome3 which is already installed?

Keep in mind I don't have access to the login screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure XRDP to start  cinnamon as default desktop session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135483/how-to-configure-xrdp-to-start-cinnamon-as-default-desktop-session)

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `witch` to `which` so that English translating software can work properly.

Answer (score 2):

On MY Ubuntu 16.04.4, I would stop the `xfce` service and start `gdm3`. See `man service`, and use `sudo service --status-all` to make sure the `xfce` service is running, then:

```
sudo service xfce stop
sudo service xfce status
sudo service gdm3 start
sudo service gdm3 status
```

Comment: I removed xfce and gdm3 is running but I got no desktop !!

Comment: All I got is the desktop background