# How to enable KDE via XRDP in Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 10 Hyper V?

Tags: kde, hyper-v

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 from quick create and everything works fine with Gnome. However I want to switch to KDE and installed that and also this is working fine in Hyper V local mode. If I connect via XRDP however, Gnome is still used. I changed `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh` and commented out the last two lines and added `exec startkde`:

```
#test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
#exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
exec startkde
```

However this is not working and in local mode I can see these errors in `/var/log/xrdp.log`:

```
[20231017-13:52:43] [ERROR] xrdp_sec_recv: xrdp_mcs_recv failed
[20231017-13:52:43] [ERROR] xrdp_rdp_recv: xrdp_sec_recv failed
[20231017-13:52:43] [ERROR] libxrdp_process_data: xrdp_rdp_recv failed
[20231017-13:52:43] [ERROR] xrdp_process_data_in: xrdp_process_loop failed
[20231017-13:52:43] [ERROR] xrdp_iso_send: trans_write_copy_s failed
[20231017-13:52:44] [ERROR] Sending [ITU T.125] DisconnectProviderUltimatum failed
```

I also found [How to configure XRDP to start  cinnamon as default desktop session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135483/how-to-configure-xrdp-to-start-cinnamon-as-default-desktop-session) and tried

`echo "startkde" > ~/.Xclients`

`chmod u+x ~/.Xclients`

`sudo systemctl restart xrdp.service`

However this is also not working. What is wrong?

Just saw the `/etc/xrdp/startubuntu.sh` file and this looks like it should be changed, too:

```
#!/bin/sh
# DESKTOP_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Desktop Image build process
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
exec /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

I tried it with

```
export KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5
export DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
exec /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

However still not working.

Comment: Hey, it's the prepared image from Hyper V quick create, i.e. 22.04 with Gnome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was nearly correct, only `startplasma-x11` instead of `startkde` was necessary!

Summary:

`/etc/xrdp/startubuntu.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# DESKTOP_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Desktop Image build process
export KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5
export DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
exec /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

Last 3 lines of `/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh`:

```
#test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
#exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
exec startplasma-x11
```